# DOI's hyperlink: include "doi:"?

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, pdftex, doi

The package `doi` renders `\doi{10.1000/182}` as `doi:10.1000/182`, where `10.1000/182` is a boxed or colored hyperlink.

Can the hyperlink also include the `doi:` part?  Omitting that is as peculiar as omitting the `http://` from a conventional hyperlink.  This also violates the [DOI standard](http://www.doi.org/doi_handbook/2_Numbering.html#2.6.2), which says that [standard IETF guidelines for URI representations](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-1.1.2) apply.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{doi}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{bogus} Smith, J. ``Title,'' in J. Bogosity 42(7). \doi{10.1000/182}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

I'm using pdflatex on Ubuntu 14 (pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14), and doi.sty 2007/07/24 from Ubuntu package texlive-latex-extra.  That file, doi.sty, is short enough to expect an answer that modifies that file.

Comment: Hi! This would use a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Also, you probably link the wrong page, there's no mention on _which part should be hyperlinked_, as far as I see.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please state which bibliography style you employ. Please also post a specific example of a bibliographic entry that features a `doi` field.

Comment: I've added a MWE, bib style, and bib entry, and linked to better standards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you can use `\doitext` to modify what is displayed before the doi, it will never be within the hyperlink.  To simulate `doi.sty` (without using it), you can do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\doitext}{doi:}

\newcommand*{\doi}{% 
  \begingroup 
  \lccode`\~=`\#\relax 
  \lowercase{\def~{\#}}%
  \lccode`\~=`\_\relax
  \lowercase{\def~{\_}}%
  \lccode`\~=`\<\relax 
  \lowercase{\def~{\textless}}%
  \lccode`\~=`\>\relax 
  \lowercase{\def~{\textgreater}}%
  \lccode`\~=0\relax 
  \catcode`\#=\active 
  \catcode`\_=\active 
  \catcode`\<=\active 
  \catcode`\>=\active 
  \@doi
}

%% this is the actual command which processes the argument, with the catcodes 
%% set in the previous command
%% it closes the group, and spits out the url.
\def\@doi#1{% 
  \let\#\relax
  \let\_\relax
  \let\textless\relax 
  \let\textgreater\relax 
  \edef\x{\toks0={{#1}}}% 
  \x
  \edef\#{\@percentchar23}%
  \edef\_{_}%
  \edef\textless{\@percentchar3C}% instead of {\string<} for Apple
  \edef\textgreater{\@percentchar3E}% instead of {\sting>} for Apple
  \edef\x{\toks1={\noexpand\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}}}% 
  \x
  \edef\x{\endgroup\the\toks1 {\doitext\the\toks0}}%
  \x
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\doi{test}
\end{document}
```

The only thing I changed is that I grouped `\doitext` with `\the\toks0`.  The macro `\the\toks1`, which comes before, contains the `\href` command, which then applies to the whole group.

You might want to contact one of the maintainers to ask them to make this an option in future versions of `doi.sty`.

Comment: To contact the maintainers, http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/texlive-latex-extra demands an Ubuntu One account.  I'll get around to that later.

Comment: FYI, making that one-line change in doi.sty itself works too, but only on computers using that tweaked file (not, for instance, on arxiv.org).

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune -- Contacting the maintainers that way is not likely to help: they strictly rely on TeX Live for their packages. Of course, the repackaging for Debian can lag behind the most current TeX Live release. So, currently, my version of `doi.sty` matches yours, but if the package updates, the Debian repositories will not use a more recent version until they update their whole repackaging of TeX Live. For reference, compare my version of pdfTeX: `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `\doitext` command to modify what is displayed. You may need to use something like: `\renewcommand*{\doitext}[1]{doi: #1}` See http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/doipubmed/doc/doipubmed.pdf for more details.

Comment: You should mention in your answer that `doipubmed.sty` is another package.  The OP is using `doi.sty`, which, incidentally, also has a command `\doitext` that has no argument.

Comment: This `renewcommand` causes no errors, but neither does it change the output.  Should I replace doi.sty with package doipubmed.sty?  (Sorry, I still don't have the MWE ready.)

Comment: When I change the MWE from {doi} to {doipubmed}, the hyperlink vanishes.  Mwah mwah.  Ubuntu's current doipubmed.sty is `2007/08/20 1.01 (NLCT)`.

Comment: Maybe `doipubmed` does not automatically include `hyperref`?  It's `hyperref` that's responsible for links, and `doi` pulls in `hyperref`.  So try `usepackage{hyperref,doipubmed}`.